# Show that the sequence $ln(n)$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that $\ln(n)$ diverges to $\infty$. Here is my work.

By way of contradiction, suppose that $\ln (n)$ converges to $\ell$; i.e., $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n) = \ell$. Since the natural log function is surjective, there exists $y$ such that $\ln (y) = \ell$, giving us $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln (n) = \ln(y)$, and therefore $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\ln(n) - \ln(y)) = 0$, or finally $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n/y) = 0$. Letting $k = \frac{n}{k}$, then it seems $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \ln(k) = 0$. Now, consider $\epsilon = \ln(2) > 0$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\ln(k) < \ln(2)$ for every $k \ge N \ge 1$. Hence, $k < 2$ and $k=2$ produces one of many contradictions.

Is this correct? I do have one general question relating to this that is somewhat subtle in nature: how do I formally justify the substitution? Intuitively, I realize that if $k = \frac{n}{y}$, then as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $k \rightarrow \infty$, and so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln (\frac{n}{y}) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \ln (k)$, but I am having difficulty seeing how one formally justifies this.

Comment: What's your definition of $\ln$ ?

Comment: ISTM that, since ln is strictly increasing, all you really need to do is show that for any possible limit, the logarithm gets bigger than that limit at some point (which you can construct explicitly with the exponential function).  It'll never come back down again, so you're done.

Comment: Let $n=e^k$. Then $\ln n=k$, which can be as large as you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your approach totally. But if you took a sequence of numbers $e^{n}$, then $ln(e^{n})=n$ is a sequence of points diverging to infinity; thus we cannot have convergence to any finite value.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM  $\ln x := \log_e x$, and $\log_b x$ is defined as that number such that $b^{\log_b x} = x$ and $\log_b(b^x) = x$.

Comment: @AritroPathak Well, my approach is first to show that $\ln (n/y) \rightarrow 0$ implies that $\ln(n) \rightarrow 0$, and then show that $\ln(n) \rightarrow 0$ implies a contradiction, which I believe I did. Since what we originally assumed implies a contradiction, it must be the case that $\ln (n)$ diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a proof by contradiction as well, but slightly different in order to hit at the heart of the problem:

Definition of a limit going to infinity:

We say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n) =L$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $|f(n)-L| < \epsilon$ when $n>N$.

Suppose, for sake of contradiction, that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ln(n) \neq \infty$, that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ln(n) = L$, where $L$ is a finite number. We use the definition of a limit going to infinity to say that if we set $\epsilon$ to $0.01$, there must be a number $N$ such that $|\ln(n)-L| < 0.01$ when $n>N$.

Therefore, we have if $n>N$:

$$-0.01<\ln(n)-L<0.01$$
$$-0.01+L<\ln(n)<0.01+L$$
$$e^{-0.01+L} < n < e^{0.01+L}$$
$$e^{-0.01} \cdot e^L < n <e^{0.01} \cdot e^L $$

Since $e^{0.01}$, $e^{-0.01}$, and $e^L$ are all constants, we have, **for all** $n>N$: $CD<n<CE$, where $CD$ and $CE$ are finite. Therefore, we now say that the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n=L$, where $L$ is finite and between $CD$ and $CE$.

This is a contradiction, because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n=\infty$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ln(n) \neq L$, where $L$ is finite. Therefore,  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ln(n) = \infty$, and $\ln(n)$ diverges.

**Q.E.D**

Perhaps this is slightly more rigorous that you were looking for, but you cannot simply say that you can see that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is always positive, because other functions that do converge (like $-1/x$) fulfill this requirement.

Comment: It is not necessary that $L$ is between $CD$ and $CE$ and does you write $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n=L$ as it is bounded and monotincally increasing .

Answer (score 1):

A different way: since $\exp$ is strictly increasing and goes to infinity, $\log(n) \to \infty$ iff $\exp(\log(n))$ does.

Answer (score 1):

By definitions and the particular Rieman sum with unit length intervals to the right of $x=2,$
$$\displaystyle\ln n = \int _1^n\frac{1}{t}dt \geq \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n},$$
which is famously divergent!

Comment: do you mean divergent?

Comment: This is incorrect, the harmonic series is divergent, and you should additionally add a limit to connect this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The limit game goes like this:

Pick a really big number and call it $N$.

Find a value for $n$ such that $\ln{n}\gt N$.

If you can do this no matter how big $N$ is, then $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln{n}=\infty}$.

**Edit:** you need the fact that $\ln{n}$ is monotone increasing to properly use this argument.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the main question is - as usual : "how a mathematical object is defined ?"

I will consider that $\ln$ denotes the primitive of $f:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ which vanishes at $x=1$.

From that starting point, it's easy to prove the "functional equation for the logarithm", that is :

$$\forall (x,y)\in(0,+\infty)^2,\,\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$$

Since $\ln$ is strictly increasing, there are two possibilities regarding its behavior at $+\infty$ :

- either $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln(x)=L\in\mathbb{R}$
- or $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln(x)=+\infty$

Now suppose that the first case holds. We know that, for all $x>0$ :

$$\ln(2x)=\ln(x)+\ln(2)$$

Taking the limits in both sides leads to : $L=L+\ln(2)$, a contradiction (indeed, $\ln(2)>\ln(1)=0$).

Hence, all this proves that:

> $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln(x)=+\infty$$

And, as a consequence, the sequence $(\ln(n))_{n\ge1}$ diverges to $+\infty$, just as any sequence of the form $(\ln(t_n))_{n\ge1}$ where $(\forall n\ge1,t_n>0)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=+\infty$.